# Magento 1.8.1 on VPS & set-up of HTPS

Tags: magento-1.8, configuration, ssl, https, htaccess

after recent announcement of Google to rank https/ssl site higher we are investigating how to do this.

Situation: we run Magento 1.8.1 multistore on 1 IP with 4 stores & in total 12 storeviews. Every storeview has one domain. Server is VPS on CentOs 6.5 & Direct Admin 1.45

**Question: Now what would we the steps to set-up https/ssl?**

(maybe we can collaborate and make it a wiki question)

Things I can think of

1. Buy certificate [where is best & what type for multistore that makes Google smile]
2. Correct way of installing on DA
3. Config steps in Magento (for multistore)
4. Config step in htaccess? (for multistore)
5. Method to secure SEO juice from htp site?
6. Correct all "This page contains both secure and nonsecure items""
7. Server caching issues?

There is probably a lot of information that can be found "in parts" - but what about aggregating it here

Many many thanks

Comment: While switching to HTTPS is certainly a good idea, and if it's going to take time and financial investment in your case it's worth looking into now, but bear in mind this signal is currently "a very lightweight signal—affecting fewer than 1% of global queries, and carrying less weight than other signals such as high-quality content" so you have plenty of time to switch over before it's a more important factor.  For completion, reference is here - http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal_6.html

Answer (score 1):

1. GoDaddy is not expensive and take a SSL for Company's so the
   companyname is in a green bar. The best for webshops
2. If you have a VPS (http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=15) If your doubting what your doing ask your webhoster!
3. Multistor explanation (http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup)
4. htaccess is the same URL if i readed good ;)
5. Explenation (http://moz.com/learn/seo/http-status-codes) the most is standard in Magento
6. This you can do in magento admin GoTo: System => Configuration => Web    Here you see Unsecure and Secure... if you have unsecured items on your website try change settings overhere
7. There are a lot! I have installed zend / eAccelerator / memcache / xCache. There are more options like:

   - Varnish // Can be installed on your server... there are also plugins for DirectAdmin for this
   - nginx // Can be installed on your server

You can also use expensive caching modules and working realy good!

I gave you some information where you can vind more about your questions, its a verry long go to explain everything overhere. I hope you'll understand me. If you have any questions regarding this... please let me know.

The extra options i have installed it my self on the VPS, if you dont know what your doing just ask your webhoster to do this or just contact me i can help you with this